# Need VBScript help to close Access database and shell

Tags: vbscript

I have an Access database that is open that is preventing a scheduled WinZip job from executing every night (all via Task Scheduler).  I inherited the script and am new to VBScript.  I've tried the following commands but have had no luck yet:

```
appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
appAccess.Application.Quit
Access.Quit (Object Required: 'Access" runtime error)
DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll (Object Required: 'DoCmd" runtime error
```

Here's the script I inherited/modified:

```
Dim appAccess 
set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("C:\Users\winshut\Desktop\SAP Winshuttle Extracts\SAP Data Extract 2.ACCDB")
```

Seems simple I'm just missing something.  Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have a script that opens an Access database and leaves it open? But you want it to close the database when it's done?

Comment: Correct.  The script runs a macro that runs queries and creates csv files.  Access stays open with one of the databases open.  A winzip job then runs but gets locked up due to the access database being opened